# How can I include a minus sign in this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match the following three lines:

```
usemtl ftw
kd 1.2 3.2 3.1
v  -12.1892 -53.4267 -276.4055
```

My regex matches the first two:

```
^(\w+) ((\S+)( \S+)*) *$
```

I've tried a few variants to match the negative numbers, but they just stop anything from being matched:

```
^(\w+) (([\S-]+)( [\S-]+)*) *$
^(\w+) (((\S|-)+)( (\S|-)+)*) *$
```

What am I supposed to do here? `-` isn't a special character in regex, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-` is only a special character in character classes `[...]`

Your problem comes from `v  -12.1892 -53.4267 -276.4055` containing 2 spaces in between `v` and `-12.18...`. Your regex only matches one.

Try this regex instead:

```
^(\w+)\s*((\S+)( \S+)*) *$
```

Although your regex could be simplified to (not sure exactly what you want to match and capture though):

```
^(\w+)(\s*\S+)*$
```

See it on http://rubular.com/r/D86njdYzJF

Answer (score 5):

Put it first in the class: `[-\S]`

Then it should work.

Comment: That works for the first two lines, but the last one still isn't being matched.

Comment: Try escaping it? `\-` or something perhaps?

Comment: @Rosarch - Your regex works fine, you just need to add a space after the `\w` block - as your 3rd line has 2 spaces in it.

Comment: Worked in regexp_like using Oracle

Answer (score 1):

There are two spaces between v and -12.1892 that seems to be your problem. Also to use `-` inside a character class i.e. `[...]` you need to escape it with `\-`

Comment: You don't need to escape `-` inside a character class if it is the first character after the `[` - for example, `[-0-9]` will accept negative numbers because the first `-` is read literally.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it isn't matching is because your third line has *two* spaces between the `v` and `-12.1892`. Try this:

`^(\w+) +(([\S]+)( [\S]+)*) *$` (the added `+` sign allows for multiple spaces)

Here is the jsfiddle to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/xewys/

Comment: Probably because it has an upvote. Every answer for this question that has an upvote also has a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The most basic regex I could think of to match your sample data was "(\S+\s+)+", but that might not be suitable for you - it seems too generic.