# How to write and use regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I want to write a regular expression in java which will accept the String having alphabets, numbers, - and space any number of times any where.

The string should only contain above mentioned and no other special characters. How to code the regular expression in java?

I tried the following, It works when I run it as a java application.

But the same code when I run in web application and accept the values through XML, It accepts '/'.

```
 String test1 = null;

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 test1 = scan.nextLine();

 String alphaExp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9-]*$";

 Pattern r = Pattern.compile(alphaExp);
 Matcher m = r.matcher(test1);

 boolean flag = m.lookingAt();

 System.out.println(flag);
```

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: [Doesn't match for me](http://ideone.com/GwV5eM).

Comment: Is this the correct solution according to you?

Comment: Yes. But more importantly, is that the correct solution according to *you*?

Comment: In other words: [You want to exclude all special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756567/regular-expression-for-excluding-special-characters).

Comment: @Nidhee your example does not replicate. A single `/` is not matched.

Comment: Yes @KJaeg but not '-'.

Comment: @Nidhee, Oh, didn't see the "-" in your text because it was located at an unlucky position in your text. Does it help to put it in a character class, like in the following Link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796179/how-to-include-a-minus-sign-in-this-regex
You could also try to escape it with a backslash: "\-"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use POSIX character classes (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}-]*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("asfsdf 1212sdfsd-gf121sdg5 4s");
boolean b = m.lookingAt();
```

With this regular expression if the string you pass contain anything else than alphanumeric or space characters it will be a no match result.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to contain '-' (dash).

Comment: The updated regular expression: ^[\\p{Alnum}\\p{Space}-]*$

Comment: @perbellinio I believe you can edit your post. If not, should I do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a space from the character class - since you mentioned it in your text `^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$`

You can add the `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag too so you can specify how the pattern handles the lines:

```
     String alphaExp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]*$";

     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(alphaExp, Pattern.MULTILINE);
     Matcher m = r.matcher(test1);

     boolean flag = m.lookingAt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the fact that `*` quantifier will make it match to everything including no matches (0 or more times, like empty lines or blank tokens `""`, infinitely.

If you instead use `+` ["`[\w\d\s-\]+`"](http://regexr.com/3dfl4) it will match one or more (consider using `\\` for each `\` in your Java Regex code as follow: "`[\\w\\d\\s-]+`"

Consider that `*` is a quantity operator that works as `{0, }` and `+` works like `{1, }`

Comment: Since its enclosed between `^` and `$`, the `*` quantifier makes perfect sense.

Comment: Yes, it does, but his code is taking input from a scanner.nextLine, so each input string will be a single line already. And using * it will match also blank strings while + doesn't.